# error: package com.getcapacitor.community.facebooklogin does not exist error in quasar + capacitor

Tags: android, capacitor, quasar-framework, capacitor-plugin

Package - https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login
Setup - Facebook login for Android in Quasar + Capacitor

So I just followed the instructions from the [documentation for android](https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login). Everything is working fine in web setup but when I am trying to build using android studio I am getting the error:

> error: package com.getcapacitor.community.facebooklogin does not exist

#### MainActivity.java

```java
package org.mycure.mobile.pxp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.community.facebooklogin.FacebookLogin;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
      add(FacebookLogin.class);
    }});
  }
}
```

#### Versions

- `quasar - 1.15.10`
- `@capacitor/core - 2.4.7`
- `@capacitor/android - 2.4.7`

#### Relevant links

I also saw [this issue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login/issues/7) and followed the suggested fixes but non worked. I was hoping maybe I just missed something? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to remove the Android platform and re-add it?

Comment: @jofftiquez were you able to find the answer for this ?

Comment: @power-cut unfortunately no, we dropped facebook login because of this. We created a new version of our app using the latest quasar versions so we weren't able to fix this on this version